# Selecting option in Chosen dropdown on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-chosen

In my project I have a dropdown option which displays different currency codes from around the world. This dropdown is utilising the "Chosen" jQuery plugin. On selection of a currency code, all appropriate symbols in the page change, i.e. selecting GBP will display a British pound (£) whilst USD would display a US dollar ($).

On page load, the default currency of the user is so be chosen from the list based on the model. Please see below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CurrencyCode, Model.CurrencyList != null ? Model.CurrencyList : new SelectList(new[] { "" }), Model.CurrencyCode != null ? Model.CurrencyCode.ToString() : "--Select Currency Code--", new { id = "CurrencyCode", onchange = " CurrencySymbol($('#hidesubtotal').val(), $('#hidevat').val(), $('#hidetotal').val(),$('#hidediscount').val()); ", @class = TransactionHelpers.cssClass(Validation, "CurrencyCode", "chzn-select"), style = "width:200px; text-align:left;" })
```

This works fine in both Chrome and Firefox, the correct option is selected and all relevant placeholders reflect the selection. However, when rendered in Internet Explorer this is ignored and the dropdown's default selection is "Select an Option" rather than the user's currency code, which should be pre-selected. By adding the following parameter, '@data_placeholder = Model.CurrencyCode', I am able to get IE to fill in the dropdown with the correct code, but the changes do not reflect elsewhere unless the user reselects and option.

What would be the best way to go about this so that IE reflects the changes on load without further interaction? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: As requested here is a snippet of code from the model, where a currency code is passed in the TransactionViewModel:

```
public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
```

And also the JavaScript handling:

```
    var selectedCurrency = $('#CurrencyCode option:selected').text();
    if (selectedCurrency != '--Select Currency Code--') {
        var matchedCurrecyOptions = $("#CurrencyCode option:contains('" + selectedCurrency + "')");
        if (matchedCurrecyOptions.length == 2) {
            var currencyValue = matchedCurrecyOptions[1].value;
            if (typeof currencyValue !== 'undefined') {
                $('#CurrencyCode option:selected').val(currencyValue).trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
        }
    }
```

If I make a change to the dropdown, the change is replicated across the page, but not for the initial entry.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code from your model and controller as well? I quickly tried your code and did not notice the problem.

Comment: I have made an edit in my question. I think what I really need is perhaps some JavaScript to just select whatever option is currently in the first entry of the dropdown, perhaps?

Comment: It is supposed to be the default behaviour. Could you also write what the generated HTML looks like?

Comment: I have added some of the JavaScript control into my question. The dropdown populates in IE, but the changes will not reflect across the page unless I remake the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$(function () {
  $("#currencyCode").change( function () {
    var selectedCurrency = $('#CurrencyCode option:selected').text();
    if (selectedCurrency != '--Select Currency Code--') {
        var matchedCurrecyOptions = $("#CurrencyCode option:contains('" + selectedCurrency + "')");
        if (matchedCurrecyOptions.length == 2) {
            var currencyValue = matchedCurrecyOptions[1].value;
            if (typeof currencyValue !== 'undefined') {
                $('#CurrencyCode option:selected').val(currencyValue).trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
        }
    }

  }).trigger();
});
```

Should trigger a change event on load and will reselect the chosen option.